# Why should INotifyPropertyChanged and plain events be mutually exclusive?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, wcf

## MS recommendation

[INotifyPropertyChanged Interface on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) states :

> For change notification to occur in a binding between a bound client
>   and a data source, your bound type should either:
>
> - Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (preferred).
> - Provide a change event for each property of the bound type.
>
> Do not do both.

The questions revolves around why "do not do both".

## Context

I'm writing a program that runs server side. A bunch of classes are meant to be used locally and sent as answer to HTTP clients requests using WCF (no notification to clients). For this purpore, they are generated from a XML schema (like this in a pre-build event: `"$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)xsd.exe" "$(ProjectDir)generated\SystemState.xsd" /classes /enableDataBinding /namespace:XXX /o:"$(ProjectDir)generated"` .

The `/enableDataBinding` option comes in handy to have automatic notification (all notification receivers are server-side).

This is really good for some notification receivers (server state change trigger some relevant code). Those aren't even interested in details, just to know that a property change, which makes a very good fit with INotifyPropertyChanged.

But some receivers are specifically interested in one particular property change, which makes a good fit for "plain" `MyFooChanged` events.

## Choice

I have two options:

- Write receiver code that receives the generic `PropertyChanged` event, filters based on the property name typed as a string... feels like [Code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) (error-prone, lacks compile-time checks, etc).
- Use the generic `PropertyChanged` event for the receivers where it is best, **plus** write one or two "plain" events `MyFooChanged` for the few properties that some specific receivers are interested in. All event receivers would remain simple and clean.

The second seems much cleaner but violates Microsoft recommendation.

## Does MS recommendation have a point here ?

In this context, should I really worry about Microsoft saying "Do not do both" ? Humorous tribute to XKCD below to state the spirit of the question:

[image: XKCD 608 : do not write in this space]

I think there's no problem right now, but it may be interesting to discuss reasons why Microsoft states to not do both.

- In which context would it be bad to do both ? Windows Forms ? WPF ?
- What happens if you do both ? Duplicate updates in some controls ? (From the early days of .NET 1.1 and on, most MS classes have had checks against this.)
- What else ?

Cheers,

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` can be made strongly typed (not based on magic strings) with Expressions. Still, the MSDN docs are talking about DataBinding, which is where `INotifyPropertyChanged` really matters. I don't see why server-side code would have to have any restrictions of that kind. BTW, I don't see why server-side code should be based in events...

Comment: Mutually exclusive is not the term I would use to describe that statement from Microsoft.  One does not preemptively exclude the other.

Comment: @Blam: MS wrote "do not do both", doesn't that mean the same as "mutually exclusive" ?

Comment: There's an alternative, perhaps not for all situations, but definitely interesting for some, if only for a cleaner solution to thread issues. That solution is: forget both options and instead implement observers using Reactive Extensions. Or, as an expanded study shows, perhaps do implement traditional events but consume them through `Observer.FromEventPattern` and the like. Best solution depends on use case.

Comment: What?  Look up "mutually exclusive".

Comment: Well, I read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity and it still seems to fit. Perhaps you mean that MS *asks* to not implement both, but since one *can* implement both anyway they are not *strictly* mutually exclusive? In that case, since the question title says "*should* ... be mutually exclusive" it's still okay. If your point still holds I don't see it, sorry. Feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: Let it go.  It is not the term I would use.   Should not and can not are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In which context would it be bad to do both ? Windows Forms ? WPF ?

Both support `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `PropertyNameChanged` event-based notifications, so it would apply universally when you are data-binding.

> What happens if you do both ? Duplicate updates in some controls ?

It's not very easy to answer this question (a definitive answer would take more than just reading the relevant source). Obviously there would be lots of needless duplicate work going on; in read-only scenarios such as this one I wouldn't exactly expect fireworks.

> What else?

The main problem as I see it is lack of consistency, which leads to misunderstanding, which leads to bad code.

If there are no special factors into play strongly suggesting to do otherwise, I 'd go with just `INotifyPropertyChanged` because it's well-known, immediately understood and goes lighter on the event handlers. You can [use expression trees](https://www.google.gr/#hl=en&q=inotifypropertychanged+expression+trees) to make it strongly typed, too.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning expression trees to get strong typing back.